# Reciting silently in salah

Tags: salat, fiqh, hanafi, qiraat

Salam. I am a hanafi. I know its waajib to recite silently in zuhr and asr, but what is the definition of reciting silently. Also there are words that are not properly pronounced in Surah Faith when reciting silently like "ض"، ط and غ. What should I do with these words.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. You should explain what you mean by your pronunciation issue on letters such as ظ، ض  and غ.

Answer (score 1):

Reciting silently means simply only you can hear what you are reciting. I do not understand why some letters must be read aloud. Da, Dha and Qa are no different than the other letters.

Answer (score 0):

reciting silently is called 'ikhfat'. Recognizing ikhfat is according to the convention.(As you may know it is called orf - عرف)
As soon as you get it, you can see it is not hard to recite any of the letters you said.